# Button registering being clicked

Tags: javascript

I'm currently trying to thirtyMinDelayButton to register that it has been clicked. I have looked around trying to find a way that would allow for the eventlistener to determine if the button has been clicked. So far I've used .queryselector to get the class name as well as .getElementByID and neither of those seem to work. How is it that I should set this up so it would register that the button was clicked and then take me to changes.html?

```
var thirtyMinDelayButton = document.getElementById(".30-minute-delayed-button");
var hourDelayButton = document.getElementById(".hour-delayed-button");
var cancelledButton = document.getElementById(".cancelled-button");

/*update changes*/
function thirty_min_delay(){
    document.querySelector("thirtyMinuteDelayButton") = "changes.html";


}
function hour_delay(){
    document.querySelector("hourDelayButton") = "changes.html";
}
function cancelled(){
    document.querySelector("cancelledButton") = "changes.html";
}

/*
 * event listeners
 */
thirtyMinDelayButton.addEventListener("click", thirty_min_delay, false);
hourDelayButton.addEventListener("click", hour_delay, false);
cancelledButton.addEventListener("click", cancelled, false);
```

Then the HTML is:

```
<article id="contentstart">
                <h2>Football</h2>
                <p>Click a button below to update the schedule.</p> 
                <div class="changes">
                    <p class="30-minute-delayed-button">30 Minute Delay</p>
                    <p class="hour-delayed-button">hour Delay</p>
                    <p class="cancelled-button">Cancelled</p>
                </div>
            </article>
```

Comment: Do your IDs really start with a dot?  Or is that a typo?  What is your HTML?  Also, what on earth are you trying to do inside your functions?

Comment: `getElementById` should have an id, which starts with `#`, or you can use `document.queryselector` with classNames

Comment: For one, you should include your HTML so people can tell what your elements are. Second, what are you trying to achieve by setting the result of document queries to a string? You should be using the result of the query. Third, querySelector needs to take in a selector, so if these are class names, you should be passing `".hourDelayButton"`, the . indicating a css class. Fourth, again assuming these are class names, you don't use `document.getElementById`, this looks for an element with the given ID. Instead use `document.getElementsByClassName` and this _doesn't_ need a dot like querySelector

Comment: @ArjunKomath, getElementById and similar functions (like getElementsByClassName) do not take the css selector syntax, just the plain string Id or class name.

Comment: @obermillerk `var el = document.querySelector(".myclass");` is valid, you can confirm the same here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector

Comment: I'm not saying that's invalid, that is very much valid. `var el - document.getElementById("#myid");` is not valid, it should be `document.getElementById("myid")`

Comment: I'm brand new to all of this as I'm going through a class so sorry I don't know this, but I included the class names as well up above. If I'm supposed to use the # instead of the . I didn't know I have been seeing it done with a dot in my text book.

Answer (score 0):

Change classes to ID (which should be unique), or else if you want to select via class either use `document.querySelector` or `document.getElementsByClassName`, both of which will return a collection of nodes.

```
        <article id="contentstart">
            <h2>Football</h2>
            <p>Click a button below to update the schedule.</p> 
            <div class="changes">
                <p id="30-minute-delayed-button">30 Minute Delay</p>
                <p id="hour-delayed-button">hour Delay</p>
                <p id="cancelled-button">Cancelled</p>
            </div>
        </article>
```

While using `getElementById`, always provide the plain string id.

```
var thirtyMinDelayButton = document.getElementById("30-minute-delayed-button");
var hourDelayButton = document.getElementById("hour-delayed-button");
var cancelledButton = document.getElementById("cancelled-button");

/*update changes*/
function thirty_min_delay(){
    document.querySelector("thirtyMinuteDelayButton") = "changes.html";
}
function hour_delay(){
    document.querySelector("hourDelayButton") = "changes.html";
}
function cancelled(){
    document.querySelector("cancelledButton") = "changes.html";
}

/*
 * event listeners
 */
thirtyMinDelayButton.addEventListener("click", thirty_min_delay, false);
hourDelayButton.addEventListener("click", hour_delay, false);
cancelledButton.addEventListener("click", cancelled, false);
```

Comment: Alright that fixed my issue I believe plus it makes a lot more sense now.

Comment: If you have any doubt regarding these DOM APIs, you can always refer https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/

There is plenty of sample code also available.